# What does "aufschieben" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Vorsichtig ***schiebt*** die Katze die Tür zum Flur ***auf***.

Comment: Nach dem Schieben ist die Tür auf. Die Katze schiebt. Die Tür führt zum Flur.

Comment: aufschieben = to slide open

Comment: Based on context it would mean " The cat carefully (slowly) shoves (pushes) the door towards the hallway."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Aufschieben" usually means "to postpone" but in this context "to slide open". In my understanding, it implies that the door is a sliding door. 
Although the author may have intended that the cat pushes a regular door open by squeezing itself through the gap, but it can be expressed better.